# How to get content to push footer down (using UiBinder & DockLayoutPanel)?

Tags: gwt

How can I get my content to push the footer further down the screen? The content disappears instead of pushing the footer further down (like we see on the SO home page).

I am using UiBinder, `DockLayoutPanel`, and CSS along with GWT 2.5.1.

My UiBinder xml is as follows (here's a [link to the file](https://github.com/justinhrobbins/FlashCards_App/blob/8e9fa30646d296b4b8798db0e33f6d7dd069faf9/FlashCards_GWT/src/main/java/org/robbins/flashcards/client/ui/desktop/ShellViewImplDesktop.ui.xml))

```xml
<g:DockLayoutPanel unit='PX' styleName="{style.shellStyles.wrap}">
<g:north size='180'>
    <g:HTMLPanel styleName='{style.shellStyles.header}'>
        <div id="login" class="{style.shellStyles.login}">
            <g:InlineLabel ui:field="loggedInUser"/>
            <g:InlineHyperlink ui:field="loginLogoutLink"/>
        </div>
        <h1><a href="/">Flash Cards Application</a></h1>
    </g:HTMLPanel>
</g:north>
<g:south size="70">
    <g:HTMLPanel styleName="{style.shellStyles.footer}">
        <g:Label>&copy; Copyright by Justin Robbins</g:Label>
    </g:HTMLPanel>
</g:south>
<g:center>
    <g:HTMLPanel styleName='{style.shellStyles.content}'>
        <g:SimplePanel styleName='{style.shellStyles.left}' ui:field="navigationPanel" />
        <g:ScrollPanel styleName='{style.shellStyles.right}' ui:field='contentPanel' alwaysShowScrollBars="false" />
        <div style="clear: both;" ></div>
    </g:HTMLPanel>
</g:center>
```

Excerpt of CSS is as follows (here's a [link to the full CSS](https://github.com/justinhrobbins/FlashCards_App/blob/master/FlashCards_GWT/src/main/java/org/robbins/flashcards/client/ui/desktop/style/ShellStyles.css)):

```css
.wrap {
    width: 820px;
    margin: 20px auto 10px auto;
}
@sprite .header {
gwt-image: "headerImage";
background-color: #efefef;
height: 180px;
}
@sprite .content {
    gwt-image: "contentImage";
    background-color: #efefef;
    padding: 10px 40px 20px 20px;
    min-height: 500px;
}
.left {
    width: 210px;
    float: left;
}
@sprite .left h4 {
    gwt-image: "sidebarImage";
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    color: #fff;
}
.right {
    width: 530px;
    float: right;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-right: 60px;
}
@sprite .footer {
    gwt-image: "footerImage";
    background-color: #efefef;
    height: 70px;
    line-height: 70px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}

*{margin:0; padding:0;}
body {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 12px; 
    background: #efefef;
    color: #232323; 
    margin:0; 
    padding:0;
    line-height: 150%;
}
```

**Update**: opowell's suggestion of moving contents the of South panel to Center helps. The footer is now pushed down. But now the content extends down below the bottom of the screen but no scrollbar appears. any suggestions for getting a scrollbar now?  I've created a [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16007318/why-doesnt-this-uibinder-page-have-a-vertical-scrollbar) for the scrollbar issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it as simple moving the contents of the South panel to the Center?

```xml
<g:DockLayoutPanel unit='PX' styleName="{style.shellStyles.wrap}">
<g:north size='180'>
    <g:HTMLPanel styleName='{style.shellStyles.header}'>
        <div id="login" class="{style.shellStyles.login}">
            <g:InlineLabel ui:field="loggedInUser"/>
            <g:InlineHyperlink ui:field="loginLogoutLink"/>
        </div>
        <h1><a href="/">Flash Cards Application</a></h1>
    </g:HTMLPanel>
</g:north>

<g:center>
  <g:FlowPanel>
    <g:HTMLPanel styleName='{style.shellStyles.content}'>
        <g:SimplePanel styleName='{style.shellStyles.left}' ui:field="navigationPanel" />
        <g:ScrollPanel styleName='{style.shellStyles.right}' ui:field='contentPanel' alwaysShowScrollBars="false" />
        <div style="clear: both;" ></div>
    </g:HTMLPanel>
    <g:HTMLPanel styleName="{style.shellStyles.footer}" height="70">
        <g:Label>&copy; Copyright by Justin Robbins</g:Label>
    </g:HTMLPanel>
  </g:FlowPanel>
</g:center>
```

Comment: moving contents of South panel to Center helps.  it does serve to push the footer down.  now the content extends down below the bottom of the screen but no scrollbar appears.  any suggestions?

Comment: in second thought, you answered the question in my OP.  i'm gonna accept your answer.

Comment: wrap the contents of the new FlowPanel with a ScrollPanel (you will probably need to specify a height of 100% somewhere for the ScrollPanel and/or FlowPanel).